# How to enforce a one to many relationship when existing tables cannot be altered

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

For background, my situation is I have a database that is missing a lot of foreign key relationships.  One in particular, let's call it **Orders**, which represents orders with a composite primary key of *OrderID* and *LocationID*. The other table we'll call **OrderDetails** which has an *OrderID* but no *LocationID*.  In reality, it is impossible to have an order in two locations at once, so it was assumed that there was no need to have *LocationID* in the details table.  I didn't design it, and I can't change that.

We also have to work under the assumption there will be no support to add location id to the details table for various reasons.  We are also working with Oracle and a high volume database with many concurrent users in many locations.  Finally, there will be minimal time to change any applications that use this table.

So my question is: is this solution is feasible, or is there anything else I should try?

Say I create an intersection table, for lack of a better name **AllOrders** or whatever with primary key **OrderID**.  Now we link **Order**.*OrderID* to **AllOrders**.*OrderID* and link **OrderDetails**.*OrderID* to **AllOrders**.*OrderID*.  Would it be reasonable then to fill in **AllOrders** via a trigger on each insert to **Orders** to enforce the integrity?  I am assuming all applications are inserting details after orders or the changes to enforce would be minimal and allowed.

Are there any better solutions?  I understand we would do this differently if in charge of designing or given more leeway for fixing, but I'm trying to make the most given the constraints.

Edit --
To clarify what I am looking to accomplish, I want to treat all orders with the same ID as an equivalence class modulo location and ensure that if any order is deleted it requires all orders with the same id deleted and all child order details to be deleted.  With primary importance of no orphan details.  This has to be done with minimal application changes if possible and no redesign of existing tables if possible.

Comment: If you are just trying to be able to enforce a foreign key, why not just put a unique constraint on `OrderID` in `Orders` and create the foreign key constraint in `OrderDetails`?  Ideally, you'd want to define foreign keys based on the primary key but you're allowed to define them on any unique column.

Comment: Because OrderID is not unique, there are duplicates, the real uniqueness is OrderID and LocationID

Comment: Then what does it mean when you say "it is impossible to have an order in two locations at once"?  That seems to imply that `orderID` is unique.  If `OrderID` is not unique, I'm not sure how your new table would work.  What happens if you delete one of two rows in `Order` with the same `OrderID`?  In order to be able to figure out that you shouldn't remove the row from your new table, you'd need a rather complicated (and expensive) composite trigger with row- and statement-level sections.  That's possible but much more complicated.

Comment: We're talking about reality, what the database represents, an order, cannot be in two places at once as a physical collection of objects.  The table is designed incorrectly, that is given.  The question is how to make the most out of a bad situation.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Does the actual table have multiple rows with the same `OrderID`?  And you want to keep those duplicate rows rather than doing a one-time clean-up?  Would your new table have multiple rows with the same `OrderID`?  Or are you contemplating that you'd have a rather complex three-step trigger to be able to distinct out the `OrderID` values to create your new table?  What if there are changes from multiple sessions?

Comment: Yes it has multiple rows with the same OrderID.  A cleanup is not possible because existing applications will continue to insert based on OrderID and LocationID and there will not be an opportunity granted to do such a cleanup.  You are assuming an ideal situation where the owner of the database would allow such things, unfortunately that isn't the case here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115025/discussion-between-nlh3-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table to handle the mapping going forward.

Table: Tb_order_orderdetails

Columns: OrderID, LocationID, OrderDetailsID